# Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: ... doesn't support the Associated Domains capability

Tags: ios, angular, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

When trying to build my ionic / cordova app to my iphone it currently fails with the exception Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: ... doesn't support the Associated Domains capability. (in target 'MyApp' from project 'MyApp'). When building it for the emulator the app just works fine. It already worked on my iphone before but now i just have no idea why it fails. 
Maybe someone could help me figure out a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that i only had a free personal apple developer account. I found out that apple supports different capabilities for free and paid members. You can find those here: https://developer.apple.com/support/app-capabilities/ So basically the associated domains capability which i had added to my project was not supported for me as a free member.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** While this may not be the answer for the question above, it is the solution for the same "error message" if you changed your project configs and didn't update the certificates.

This happened to me after adding associated-domains to `Runner.entitlements`. I had to update all the certificates used by the CI/CD (Bitrise).

Run the commands below as follow.

```
fastlane match appstore --readonly false --force
fastlane match adhoc --readonly false --force
fastlane match development --readonly false --force
```

After that rebuild.

Comment: That's the good stuff. Thank you